# Redirecting through .htaccess using a wildcard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

How can I do a wildcard redirect in .htaccess file?

I tried using the following, but the `*` doesn't work for some reason.

`redirect 301 /threads/*.343/ http://myotherdomain.com/threads/*.343/`

I can't use mod_rewrite, because I have 7000 of these redirects that I need to do, and apparently, when I tried about half of those, my server threw out a 500 misconfiguration error.

So it seems that writing 7000 lines of the aforementioned code is somehow less intensive.

Anyway, please let me know how I could express a wildcard in that sort of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 7000 separate rewrite rules, just use [RewriteMap](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html)

1 - First create a text file with all the 7000 chosen IDs in 2 columns like this:

```
343 343
349 349
518 518
```

2 - Then define a RewriteMap in `httpd.cond` like this:

```
RewriteMap idmap txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

3 - And then enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^threads/(.*)$ http://myotherdomain.com/threads/${idmap:$1} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I have 7000 different IDs, the numbers at the end of the url code. Hence I need to write 7000 lines. If I express it in mod_rewrite like the following.

`RewriteRule ^threads/[^\.]+\.(343|225|435|677|787|89|764|865|934)/(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/threads/$1/$2 [R=301,L]`

^ Problem with this code is that having even 3500 IDs let alone 7000 causes my website to throw a server misconfiguration error (500)

Comment: well in that case: `RewriteRule ^(threads/[^.]+\.[0-9]+)/?$ http://myotherdomain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]` would be better for you.

Comment: There are specific 7000 IDs. I don't want all URLs to be redirecting, only the ones that are within the 7000 IDs.

Answer (score 3):

With mod_alias, you could use [**`RedirectMatch`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) instead:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/threads/[^/]+\.343/$ http://myotherdomain.com$0
```

This matches all URLs that match `/threads/*.343/`, `*` being any character(s) except `/`.

Comment: I am assuming 'permanent' takes care of the whole 301 redirect?

Comment: I am having a slight problem. I think it's not matching the IDs exactly. This number `343`, it seems like it accepts `3433` if the redirect states `343`. Anyway to say that the number at the end has to be exact?

Comment: Escaping the `.` will fix it, see revised answer. And yes, `permanent` is same as `301` (you can use either).